# Pass arguments of current executing function to other function dynamically

Tags: java, methods, reflection, parameters

Snippet 1

```
public static String formatDateToString(BigDecimal param1, Date param2, String param3) {
    Utils.checkNullOrEmpty(?????); //I want the function params here dynamically

}
```

Snippet 2

```
public static boolean checkNullOrEmpty(Object...values){
    for(Object value: values){
        if(value==null){
            return true;
        }
        if(value instanceof String){
            String val = (String) value;
            if(val.isEmpty()){
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

How to dynamically get the arguments of the current function. (Refer Snippet1)

This will be helpful for functions with many parameters to avoid individual null checks.

I am able to get parameter types using

```
new Object(){}.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getParameterTypes()
```

the disadvantage is it creates a new object and only gives my the types but not values.

Comment: Side note: `null` checks like this are rarely best practice. Instead, simply use the parameter values as given, and test thoroughly to ensure that `null`s aren't passed to the method (which will result in an NPE). Passing `null` into something that isn't expecting it is a coding error, not a runtime error; runtime checks are for runtime errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java doesn't have the equivalent of JavaScript's `arguments` object, and reflection doesn't provide this information. But since the parameter list dictates what arguments you'll receive, just use the parameters directly:

```
public static String formatDateToString(BigDecimal param1, Date param2, String param3) {
    Utils.checkNullOrEmpty(param1, param2, param3);
}
```

Yes, this does mean repeating the parameter names, but you can't get around that.

Comment: This is the obvious way, do you mean there is no other possibility to pass parameters without listing all parameters?

Comment: @Vamsidhar - Right.

Comment: As an additional note, if you have so many parameters, that listing them like this becomes an issue, you should rethink your design anyway. It’s even preferable to use explicit statements instead of a method consuming all at once, i.e. `Objects.requireNonNull(param1, "param1"); Objects.requireNonNull(param2, "param2"); Objects.requireNonNull(param3, "param3");`, which has the advantage of producing helpful exception messages. And it doesn’t need any loop logic.